# Efficient parsing using pyparsing

Tags: multiprocessing, python-2.6, pyparsing

I am new to the pyparsing module and am trying to parse the example strings shown below from files which are over 60000 lines. I need to extract data from each line. However the current implementation seems to be too slow. Is there something that might be redundant in my code which could be optimized ?
As of now for a 23MB file with multiprocessing I take about 2 minutes and my main performance bottle neck is the parsing routine.

```
Example strings : 
Mar 16 14:12:25.989 [ABC] [ID=0][core#16] [65536][3131927075092] random: message
    or 
Mar 23 13:57:07.888 [123] [core#2 ] [00][3851708823] random message 2

Grammar:

nums::          '0'...'9'
num::           (nums+)
words::         'a'..'z' 'A'...'Z'
word::          (words+)

colon::         ':'
time::          ((num) + colon)+ '.' + (num)
date::          (word) + (num) + (time)

open brace::    "["
close brace::   "]"

is AP::     (open brace) + (word) + (close brace)
is BP::     (open brace) + (num) + (close brace)

oct id::        (open brace) + (word) + ("=") + (num) + (close brace)
core id::       (open brace) + (word) + ("#") + (num) + (close brace)
ppm id::        (open brace) + (num) + (close brace)
oct timestamp:: (open brace) + (num) + (close brace)
hexnum::        (hexnums+)
pcap dump::     (hexnum +(":")) + (hexnum)+
tags::          (date) + (is AP|is BP)? + (oct id)? + (core id) + (ppm id)? + (oct timestamp)? + (pcap dump)?

'''

    self.num = Word(nums)
    self.word = Word(alphas)
    self.open_brace = Suppress(Literal("["))
    self.close_brace = Suppress(Literal("]"))
    self.colon = Literal(":")
    self.stime = Combine(OneOrMore(self.num + self.colon) + self.num + Literal(".") + self.num)
    self.date = OneOrMore(self.word) + self.num + self.stime
    self.is_ap = self.open_brace + self.word + self.close_brace
    self.is_bp = self.open_brace + self.num + self.close_brace
    self.oct_id = self.open_brace + Suppress(self.word) + Suppress(Literal("=")) \
            + self.num + self.close_brace
    self.core_id = self.open_brace + Suppress(self.word) + Suppress(Literal("#")) \
            + self.num + self.close_brace
    self.ppm_id = self.open_brace + self.num + self.close_brace
    self.oct_ts = self.open_brace + self.num + self.close_brace
    self.dump = Suppress(Word(hexnums) + Literal(":")) + OneOrMore(Word(hexnums))
    self.opening = Suppress(self.date) \
            + Optional(self.is_ap.setResultsName("AP")|self.is_bp.setResultsName("BP")) \
            + Optional(self.oct_id.setResultsName("oct").setParseAction(lambda toks:int(toks[0]))) \
            + self.core_id.setResultsName("core").setParseAction(lambda toks:int(toks[0])) \
            + Optional(self.ppm_id.setResultsName("ppm").setParseAction(lambda toks:int(toks[0])) \
            + self.oct_ts.setResultsName("timestamp").setParseAction(lambda toks:int(toks[0]))) \
            + Optional(self.dump.setResultsName("pcap"))
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't really find many opportunities for performance improvement, but one element that could improve is your definition of stime.

```
self.stime = Combine(OneOrMore(self.num + self.colon) + self.num + Literal(".") + self.num)
```

Assuming time always is of the form "hh:mm:ss.ccc", using OneOrMore to read the leading "hh:mm:" will always pay the penalty of trying to match "self.num + self.colon" against the seconds and decimal point before exiting the OneOrMore. You could replace OneOrMore with explicit repetition:

```
self.stime = Combine(self.num + self.colon + self.num + self.colon + self.num + Literal(".") + self.num)
```

Or use the recently added multiplication operator:

```
self.stime = Combine((self.num + self.colon)*2 + self.num + Literal(".") + self.num)
```

This change alone dropped my performance test time by about 10%.

But instead, I would really recommend using a Regex for this. There is not much loss in readability, and you collapse the multiple element matches in Combine, OneOrMore, etc. with the single Regex:

```
self.stime = Regex(r"\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d")
```

Compared to your original form, changing to Regex dropped my performance test time by 25%.

(There is no need to go overboard on this - for instance, there is no real benefit in replacing "Word(nums)" with "Regex(r"\d+")" - it turns out that Word internally uses a regex already.)

I also reformatted your self.opening definition to use the call-syntax for defining results names - I find this form to be easier to follow:

```
self.opening = (Suppress(self.date) 
        + Optional(self.is_ap("AP") | self.is_bp("BP")) 
        + Optional(self.oct_id("oct")  .setParseAction(lambda toks:int(toks[0]))) 
        + self.core_id("core")         .setParseAction(lambda toks:int(toks[0])) 
        + Optional(self.ppm_id("ppm")  .setParseAction(lambda toks:int(toks[0])) 
        + self.oct_ts("timestamp")     .setParseAction(lambda toks:int(toks[0])))
```

There is no performance benefit, but you don't have to read around all the ".setResultsName" junk. (I'm also not a big fan of backslashes.